# Finding a preceding node that corresponds to a following node with XPath only

Tags: xml, xpath, overlap, milestone

I have a "milestone"-markup intertwingled with normal XML:

```
<root>
   <milestone type="opener" xml:id="m1" />
   text
      <milestone type="opener" xml:id="m2"/>
          text
      <milestone type="closer" ref="#m2"/>  
      text
      <node>
         text
      </node>
      ... 
   <milestone type="closer" ref="#m1"/>
</root>
```

and want to address the "parent"-milestone structure (i.e. `milestone@xml:id='m1'`) to `<node>` using nothing than XPath.

Every `milestone@xml:id` corresponds with a `milestone@ref` as opener and closer of the milestone structure.

The "parent"-milestone-structure to the node would be identified by something similar to

```
node/preceding::milestone/concat('#',@xml:id) = node/following:milestone/@ref
```

This test relies on the context of the `<node>`. It could be implemented in XSLT with something like

```
<xsl:template match="node">
  <xsl:variable name="me" select="."/>
  <xsl:value-of select="./preceding::milestone[
       ./concat('#',@xml:id) =
       $me/following::milestone/@ref
    ][1]/@xml:id" />
</xsl:template>
```

But I cannot figure out how to do that with pure XPath.

Any suggestions?

Comment: By the way to make you above example work you have to remove the `./` before `concat('#',@xml:id)`.

Comment: I'm not fully sure what you want to do. Could you extend the question with an example for input (is the context the `<node/>` element?) and expected output?

Comment: I've to prepare an import filter for an application being able to read only XPath in the input (what it does afterwards I don't know unfortunately). The application should create a "link" between the `<node/>` (i.e. it's (generated) ID) and the structure created by the milestones. In the given example `milestone[@xml:id='m1']` would be a correct output, `milestone[@xml:id='m2']` incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the variable `$me` with `current()`.

Comment: `current()` is XSLT-only, the user asked for a pure XPath solution.